Create an empty schema with struct inside
Hello guys i have a small question today, something that i want to set when i create an empty dataframe
i want to set an empty schema if the json that i receive is the field "data" empty
i have the next code :
empty_schema = StructType([
     StructField('responseStatus', StringType(), True),
     StructField("data", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
     StructField('responseDetails', StructType([
         StructField('pagesize', IntegerType(), True),
         StructField('pageoffset', IntegerType(), True),
         StructField('size', IntegerType(), True),
         StructField('total', IntegerType(), True)
         ]))
     ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD(), empty_schema)

df = df.fillna({
            "responseStatus": "SUCCESS",
            "data" : [],
            "responseDetails": {
                "pagesize": 0,
                "pageoffset": 0,
                "size": 0,
                "total": 0
            }
})


df.show()

But I'm having this error:
IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value type java.util.ArrayList ([]).

The idea is just have something like :
{
    "responseStatus": "SUCCESS",
    "data": [],
    "responseDetails": {
        "pagesize": 0,
        "pageoffset": 0,
        "size": 0,
        "total": 0
    }
}

can somebody help me?
Regards

On what line is the error? I guess it's with fillna. If you replace [] by "[]" as "data" value, does it run without error?

not very clear, but my guess is [] is causing the error. [] is nothing to spark. func.array() is.

You cannot use fill for ArrayType and StructType columns: "The replacement value must be an int, float, boolean, or string."
Try withColumn with when/otherwise:
df = df.fillna(
    {
        "responseStatus": "SUCCESS",
    }
)
df = df.withColumn("data", F.when(df.data.isNull(), F.array()).otherwise(df.data))
df = df.withColumn(
    "responseDetails",
    F.when(
        df.responseDetails.isNull(),
        F.struct(
            F.lit(0).alias("pagesize"),
            F.lit(0).alias("pageoffset"),
            F.lit(0).alias("size"),
            F.lit(0).alias("total"),
        ),
    ).otherwise(df.responseDetails),
)
df.show()

